# Why are OpenGL texture params GLint and not GLenum?

Tags: opengl

Some of the OpenGL texturing functions accept `GLint`s where I would expect a `GLenum`. For example, `glTexImage2D` has the following parameter:

```
GLint internalformat
```

The docs describe that param as follows:

> internalformat
>
> Specifies the internal format of the texture. Must be one of the following symbolic constants: GL_ALPHA, GL_LUMINANCE, GL_LUMINANCE_ALPHA, GL_RGB, GL_RGBA.

Most of the time, the API would use a `GLenum` when the value must be one of several symbolic constants. And that makes sense. But this one (and some other texture-related params) are `GLint`s. Why?

Of course, they're all integers at heart, and in C the distinction hardly matters. But it's not a purely academic question. In other, more strongly-typed languages' OpenGL bindings, the distinction between `GLint` and `GLenum` is important, because one is signed and the other isn't. E.g. in the Haskell `OpenGLRaw` package, all symbolic constants are `GLenums`, which means you must explicitly convert with `fromIntegral` every time you call `glTexImage2D` and similar functions.

Comment: It actually does not matter as much as you would think that `GLint` is signed and `GLenum` is not, because at its heart GL only allocates half of the possible 32-bit space for use by enumerants. Some really old GL extensions violate this principle, but there are effectively only 16-bits worth of enumerant values to go around. You can read more about this [here](http://www.opengl.org/registry/doc/enums.html) if you find that sort of thing interesting.

Comment: I'm not concerned about misinterpreting the high byte, if that's what you mean. Per the final paragraph of my question above, the problem really arises in languages that won't let you use the types interchangeably.

Comment: For languages with strongly typed enums, it would make sense to me to define bindings with specific enum types. At least for the ones I have seen (mostly thinking of Java bindings), unfortunately that has not been done.

Comment: "it would make sense to me to define bindings with specific enum types."--It depends on the language and the binding library. Sometimes, the library author chooses to paper over that inconsistency and use enums for everything that's enum-like. Other times, that's not done. E.g. in Haskell's OpenGLRaw.

Comment: @Jarrett: Not sure if we're talking about the same thing. What I was suggesting is to have specific enums. Say a BlendFunc enum that only has the values for valid blend functions. A PrimitiveType enum for valid primitive types. A BufferType enum for valid buffer types. Etc. And then define the entry points to take these specific enum types as arguments.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Once upon a time... If you go back to the documentation for older OpenGL versions, where the functionality that is now deprecated in the Core Profile is still documented, this will make sense. It used to be legal to pass values 1, 2, 3, 4 for `internalFormat`, denoting the number of color components in the texture.

For example, this is the man page for `glTexImage2D` in OpenGL 2.1: http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man2/xhtml/glTexImage2D.xml. Under `internalFormat`, it says:

> Specifies the number of color components in the texture. Must be 1, 2, 3, or 4, or one of the following symbolic constants: ...